# Setting security for a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I have two groups: group A and group B. And I have six users: 1,2,3,4,5,6.

- Group A includes: 1,2,3,4
- Group B includes: 5,6

How to set up rights to the folder for the two groups to access the folder A had access to two groups and folder B only group B ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line in your question is hard to understand but If I understand it all you need to do is just set up your two groups, add those users to the groups then give both GroupA and GroupB permission to do whatever on FolderA and only give GroupB permission to do whatever on FolderB.

Here are some Instructions on how to do some of those tasks.

- [How to create group accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783323%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Changing Group Membership](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781712%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Setting User and Group Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758166%28WS.10%29.aspx)